# Swift: What is the difference between 'Currying' and the function that return a function?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, currying

```
//  function 1------- Currying   
    func increment (incrementBy x: Int)(y: Int) -> Int {
       return x + y
    }

//  function 2------- The function that return a function
    func increment(incrementBy x: Int) -> ((Int) ->Int){
       func incrementFunc(y: Int){
           return x + y
       }
    }
```

Do that two functions do the same thing , don't they? And I can use them in a same way. Like this:

```
let incrementFunc = increment(incrementBy: 10)
var number = 10
number = incrementFunc(number)
```

So, I am confused, what is the difference of them? What is the advantages of each way?

Comment: Just a side note currying will most likely be removed in the next version of Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first example you have is "syntactic sugar" for the second one, in a similar way that `[Int]` is shorthand for `Array<Int>`. They mean the same thing and act the same way.

**However**, I should point out that this syntactic sugar is going away soon. [This proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md), written by a Swift compiler engineer and accepted by the Swift development team, says that the shorthand currying syntax will no longer be a part of the language. Instead, all currying will be done the way your second example is written.

Comment: Basically, the first one (the syntactic sugar) says, "Swift, please curry this function _for_ me."

Answer (score 1):

First function 2 should be:

```
func increment(incrementBy x: Int) -> ((Int) ->Int){
    func incrementFunc(y: Int) -> Int {
        return x + y
    }
    return incrementFunc
}
```

In this case the function 1 & 2 do exactly the same thing.
The first one is a little bit shorter.
The second one seems to be clearer in its intent.

You can also us function 3 which is shorter and clear:

```
func increment(incrementBy x: Int) -> ((Int) ->Int){
    return { y in return x + y }
}
```